# How to get only head and tail text of some DOMNode?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

How can I get only head and tail text of nodes in DOMDocument?

Example, in this sample code I don't want to see contents of  tag:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <test>head text <b>some bold text</b> tail text</test>
</root>
');

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('test') as $node) {
    echo 'nodeValue: '.$node->nodeValue."\n";
    echo 'textContent:'.$node->textContent."\n";
}
```

Comment: please show us what you expect to get or explain the wanted result better

Comment: I would have thought they want just `head text`  and `tail text`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to go through each node and look for just the child nodes which are text (DOMText), any other node can be ignored...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <test>head text <b>some bold text</b> tail text</test>
</root>
');

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('test') as $node) {
    foreach ( $node->childNodes as $sub )   {
        if ( $sub instanceof DOMText )  {
            echo 'nodeValue: '.$sub->nodeValue."\n";
            echo 'textContent:'.$sub->textContent."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Gives you...

```
nodeValue: head text 
textContent:head text 
nodeValue:  tail text
textContent: tail text
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could also use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and an xpath expression to get the text:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <test>head text <b>some bold text</b> tail text</test>
</root>
');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('/root/test/text()');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeValue;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/5kkep)